# frida calling method raises error pointer expected

Tags: android, frida

i have a java method i am trying to call manually

`public static native Object a(int i, int i2, long j, String str, Object obj);`

whenever i try to call it and pass the needed arguments it raises a error pointer expected
the obj parameter is a string list this is the code i tried

```
var e = ["string1","string2"];
var arr = Java.array('java.lang.String', e);
var x = Java.use("ms.bd.o.k")
x.a.overload('int', 'int', 'long', 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Object').call(x, 50331649, 0, 140734272498240, url, arr)
```

i also tried changing the overload to
`.overload('int', 'int', 'long', 'java.lang.String', '[java.lang.String')`
this raises the error below

```
Error: a(): argument types do not match any of:
        .overload('int', 'int', 'long', 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Object')
    at X (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:563)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:967)
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:547)
    at <anonymous> (/script1.js:94)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:193)
    at ms_bd_c_h_a (/script1.js:99)
    at apply (native)
    at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:13)
    at c (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:23)
```

Comment: Where do you got the method signature from, are you sure it is correct? And I am not sure how good Frida is able JNi methods (methods that are `native`).

Comment: @Robert i got the method signature from the code after i decompiled the app i also put a wrong overload and copy pasted the one frida provided

Comment: i think the problem arises from casting the string list to a `java.lang.object` since its throws the same error as `Java.cast(Java.array('java.lang.String', ["a"]), Java.use("java.lang.Object"))` Java.array does not returns a pointer and the cast method needs a pointer do you know any way to retrieve the pointer of a array using frida

Comment: This is what I managed to do.
But the result is somewhat discouraged.
I suggest the author to exchange contacts. Java.perform(function () { var classname = "ms.bd.o.k"; var classmethod = "a"; var methodsignature = "public static native java.lang.Object a(int,int,long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)"; var hookclass = Java.use(classname); hookclass.a.overload("int","int","long","java.lang.String","java.lang.Object").implementation = function (v0,v1,v2,v3,v4) { var ret = this.a(v0,v1,v2,v3,v4); console.log(eval(v0)+"\n"); console.log(v1+"\n"); console.log(v2+"\n"); console.log(v3+"\n"); consol